# Scatter plot of dataframe1, with marker style determined by continuous variable in dataframe2

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot data from `DataFrame1`, with the marker style determined by the value of a continuous variable in `DataFrame2`.

`DataFrame1` contains information on the difference between speeds over time, by month. `DataFrame2` contains the results from a test of statistical significance.

I would like to indicate when the differences is significant by changing the marker style if values are less than `0.05`.

What I have so far will plot the `DataFrame1` nicely, but I'm not sure how to incorporate `df2`. Perhaps by zipping the dataframes?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Some fake data
months = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
periods = np.arange(1950, 1960, 1)  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,12), index=periods, columns=months)   # Value to be plotted
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,12), index=periods, columns=months)    # Determine marker shape

colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1.1, len(months)))

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))  
for c, mmm in zip(colors, months):
    plt.scatter(df1.index, df1[mmm], color=c)
plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.title("Change in speed")
```

Current output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way is to split your `dataframe1` in tow sub dataframes: one for the values of `dataframe2` below, one for the values above. Then you can make two `scatter` calls with different markers.

Note: because we are doing two scatter plots per month, the months label in legend are duplicated. I solve this by setting one of them to `''` and the other to them to the matching `month`.

Here the whole code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Some fake data
months = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
periods = np.arange(1950, 1960, 1)  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,12), index=periods, columns=months)   # Value to be plotted
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,12), index=periods, columns=months)    # Determine marker shape

colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1.1, len(months)))

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))  
for c, mmm in zip(colors, months):
    # First sub dataframe1 where df2 values are below 0.05
    df1_plot_below = df1[df2[mmm] < 0.05]
    plt.scatter(df1_plot_below.index, df1_plot_below[mmm], color=c, marker="v", label="")

    # First sub dataframe1 where df2 values are above 0.05
    df1_plot_above = df1[df2[mmm] >= 0.05]
    plt.scatter(df1_plot_above.index, df1_plot_above[mmm], color=c, marker="^", label=mmm)

plt.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
plt.title("Change in speed")
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]